# PNG darker than render

Tags: rendering

I am totally new to using Blender. The problem I am having is this, after rendering I save the file and I get a PNG that is darker.

I'm working with Filmic Log color space at high contrast and save as render in PNG format.

Does anyone know why?

[image: images]

Thank you

Comment: Hi :). There are many similar questions on this site, feel free to search and read them :). But if i remember, one reason is the PNG exporter has some technical limits, and it's not easy to solve them.

Comment: Nice to see I am not the only one that uses that naming convention for my images.